# Citing the name of the collaboration/first author only with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing

I want to cite a collaboration using the `natbib` package.

`bibliography.bib` is something like:

```
@article{entry_name,
    author={{CollaborationName} and {Author1} and {Author2}},
    year=2013
}
```

`\cite{entry_name}` gives CollaborationName et al. (2013).

How can I get CollaborationName (2013)?

Comment: Which `bibliographystyle` are you using?

Comment: You need to use a bibliographystyle of Author Year type.  `natbib` is a standard choice for such with `bibtex`.  With `biblatex` there are many other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

The string "et al." is hard coded and is done by bibtex related to your bst-file. You can't change it such simple. As mentioned if you use `biblatex` it is possible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
 title={Test title},
 author={{CollaborationName} and {Author1} and {Author2}},
 journal="journal",
 year=2013
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxbibnames=6,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citefirst}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\citefirst{test}



\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: So there is no way to do the same thing using natbib?

Comment: @dPol: No way is wrong. It is possible but very difficult. And I don't know whether it is worth or not.